# Modify www of my domain name

Tags: url-rewriting

Let's say I have the site, http://www.Tom.com and I provide services to several neighboring cities.  If I wanted to use http://CityHere.Tom.com and http://OtherCity.Tom.com, and have different content on each of these city specific pages and yet still have my main page, http://www.tom.com still be my normal default landing page, what would I need to do?  I don't know the terms to use so googling was a bit futile.  If you can't answer the how, can you provide me the terms to use to google this topic?

I'm using ColdFusion on a Windows server.

Comment: Are you linking to these URLs? I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: If I can make the city pages a landable page, then yes, I'd link to them.  This is for SEO purposes in that having the city name in the domain is favorable - or at least this is my understanding from my research.

Comment: Google these terms, "subdomain", "iis" and "host headers". That should get you closer to your answer, or perhaps allow you to rephrase your question with more details. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use .htaccess for that first you have to set up wildcard A / AAAA record for you domain

```
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
```

you would add which subdomain's you want to exlude

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+)\.tom\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?city=%1 [L]
```

this would redirect you to content from **tom.com?city=Somecity**
however depending your server side language you have to first detect where user comes from.
Or do it client side

```
$.getJSON('//smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?', function(data) {
top.location.replace(data.city+".tom.com");         
});
```